# get format of ISO date input python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

I am getting a json object, with a string representing the data in this form:
'2018-07-09T09:58:11.809Z'

What is the format for it?

I've tried:

```
'%Y %B %d %H %M %S'
```

but i'm not sure what the T and the Z is, and how to work with them.

Comment: Are you trying to parse it ? How about using relevant [datetime's parsing function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) ?

Comment: If you're asking what the T and the Z mean, the T separates the date from the time of day. Z means Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).